# My function skips a loop parameter in c++

Tags: c++, function, loops, infinite-loop

My GetMark() function, which is supposed to check for correct range and afterwards return the value, if correct to the given array gets stuck in a infinite loop when a parameter is given outside of the accepted range, before i added the SearchMark() function it worked correctly and looped only until the user finally entered a value in the given range (0 - 100) but now after the first out of range value is given it loops no matter what is entered, I will be thankful for any suggestions. full code:

```
int GetMark(int ModuleIndex) //user input function
{
    bool help;
    if (ModuleIndex < 0 || ModuleIndex >100)
    {
        help = false;
        while (help != true)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "hey, that's a invalid value, try again!" << endl;
            GetMark(ModuleIndex);
            if ((ModuleIndex > 0) &&( ModuleIndex < 101))
            {
                help = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return ModuleIndex;
}

int SearchMark(int A[], int a) //search grades array for numbers of specific grades
{
    int i = 0;
    int ii = 0;

    while (i < 12)
    {
        if (A[i] == a)
            ii++;
        i++;
    }
    cout << "Mark " << a << " was found: " << ii << " times" << endl;
    return 0;
}



int main()
{
    int marks[12]; 
    int i = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    int grades[12];

    while (i < 12)
    {
        cout << "enter mark (0 - 100): " << endl;
        cin >> marks[i];
        GetMark(marks[i]);
        sum = sum + marks[i];
        if (marks[i] > 69)
        {
            grades[i] = 1;
        }
        else if (marks[i] > 59 && marks[i] < 70)
        {
            grades[i] = 2;
        }
        else if (marks[i] > 49 && marks[i] < 60)
        {
            grades[i] = 22;
        }
        else if (marks[i] > 39 && marks[i < 50])
        {
            grades[i] = 3;
        }
        else if (marks[i] < 35)
        {
            grades[i] = 4;
        }
        i++;
    }
    sum = sum / 12;
    cout << "your average is: " << sum  << endl;




    if (sum > 69)
    {
        cout << "You passed with 1st!" << endl;
    }
    else if ((sum > 59) && (sum < 70))
    {
        cout << "You passed with 2i!" << endl;
    }
    else if ((sum > 49) && (sum < 60))
    {
        cout << "You passed with 2ii!" << endl;
    }
    else if ((sum > 39) && (sum < 50))
    {
        cout << "You passed with 3rd!" << endl;
    }
    else if (sum < 40)
    {
        cout << "Your average is too low! You failed." << endl;
    }


    i = 0;
    while (i < 12)
    {
        if (marks[i] < 35)
        {
            cout << "Referred in module " << i + 1 << " mark too low." << endl;
        }
        i++;
    }

    SearchMark(grades, 1);
    SearchMark(grades, 2);
    SearchMark(grades, 22);
    SearchMark(grades, 3);
    SearchMark(grades, 4);

    return 0;
}`
```

Comment: Aside from the questionable use of recursion instead of simple iteration, I note that the value of ModuleIndex never changes once GetMark is called. So if it's out of range, you simple recurse again and again infinitely with that same out-of-range value.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson it does change, if it's out of range it prompts the user for new input value everytime

Comment: it prompts, yes. But it doesn't read the user's response to the prompt.

Comment: The code can be optimized through changing it radically. Why this e.g `   cin >> marks[i];
   GetMark(marks[i])`?

Comment: If called, `GetMark()` does not read any value, and calls itself recursively with the value passed to it.    That results in infinite recursion.   The code after the recursive call of `GetMark()` is never reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That function is overly complicated for what it does. Just loop while the value is bad, and prompt for a new value:

```
int GetMark(int ModuleIndex) {
    while (ModuleIndex < 0 || ModuleIndex > 100) {
        std::cout << "Invalid value.\n"
        std::cin >> ModuleIndex;
    }
    return ModuleIndex;
}
```

Recursion is very handy in theoretical analysis, but in practice it's almost always a mistake.

Comment: Thank you, with the addition of cin.ignore() and cin.clear() to enhance error handling, this works perfectly :)

Comment: @Sami -- yes, I left out the bells and whistles to make the logic clear.

Answer (score 1):

You need to allow the user to specify a new value of marks[i] / ModuleIndex within GetMarks. After clearing cin, read a new value from cin. You also need to return that value so that main's marks[i] can be updated with that value instead of the original out-of-range value.

Comment: +1. But the function **does** return the value. The problem is that the value returned by the (ghastly) recursive call isn't used, so the updated value is thrown away.

Comment: So what would you suggest? Because i can't really think of a better way to declare this function without the recursion....

Comment: I'd suggest Iteration. while(ModuleIndex < 0 || ModuleIndex > 100) { read new ModuleIndex }

Answer (score 1):

It is apparently in you `getMark`, inside the `while` loop you are calling `getMark` recursively with the same invalid `ModuleIndex` value. So you need to get it from the standard input before recursion. e.g:

```
int GetMark(int ModuleIndex){
    bool help;
    if (ModuleIndex < 0 || ModuleIndex > 100){
        help = false;
        while (help != true){
                cout << "enter new ModuleIndex: \n";
                cin >> ModuleIndex;
                GetMark(ModuleIndex);
                // ...
        }

        return ModuleIndex;
    }
```

Your code is unreadable, in addition you can use class `std::vector`.

I propose to test this code:

```
int GetMarkIndex(const std::vector<double>& vMarks, const double Search) {
    auto beg{ vMarks.begin() }, end{ vMarks.end() };
    while (beg != end && *beg != Search)
        ++beg;
    return beg != end ? beg - vMarks.begin() : -1;
}

int main() {

    std::vector<double> marks(5);
    int value;

    auto i{ 0U };
    auto sz{ marks.size() };
    while (i != sz) {
        std::cout << "Enter marks 1-->100" << std::endl;
        if (cin >> value && value > 0 && value < 101) {
            marks[i] = value;
            ++i;
        }
        else
            std::cout << "Invalid input!" << std::endl;
    }

    for (auto e : marks)
        cout << e << ", ";
    std::cout << std::endl;

    double Search = 15;
    auto index{GetMarkIndex(marks, Search)};

    (index != -1) ? (std::cout << Search << " Found at index: " << index) : (std::cout << Search << " Not found!" << std::endl);


    std::cout << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need to do is remove the recursion from this method and just rely on the while loop.  Instead of recalling the function you need to prompt for input again with the failed input and then test the value again to escape the loop.

```
int GetMark(int ModuleIndex) //user input function
{
    bool help;
    if (ModuleIndex < 0 || ModuleIndex >100)
    {
        help = false;
        while (help != true)
        {
            cin.clear();
            cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
            cout << "hey, that's a invalid value, try again!" << endl;
            cout << "enter mark (0 - 100): " << endl;
            cin >> ModuleIndex;
            if ((ModuleIndex > 0) &&( ModuleIndex < 101))
            {
                help = true;
            }
    }
}
    return ModuleIndex;
}
```

Comment: this still reads negative values and characters so it's not any good really

Answer (score 1):

The combination of the way you have defined `GetMark` and the way you use it is flawed.

No matter what you do in `GetMark`, the value entered in `main` does not change.

Change `GetMark` to:

```
int GetMark()
{
   std::cout << "enter mark (0 - 100): " << std::endl;
   int mark;
   while ( std::cin >> mark )
   {
      if (  mark >= 0 && mark <= 100)
      {
         return mark;
      }

      std::cout << "Invalid value " << mark << std::endl;
      std::cout << "enter mark (0 - 100): " << std::endl;
   }

   // Unable to read.
   // Throw exception, or exit with an error message.
}
```

and change its usage. Instead of

```
cout << "enter mark (0 - 100): " << endl;
cin >> marks[i];
GetMark(marks[i]);
```

use

```
marks[i] = GetMark();
```

---

A working version of `GetMark`:

```
int GetMark()
{
   std::cout << "enter mark (0 - 100): " << std::endl;

   std::string line;
   while ( getline(std::cin, line) )
   {
      std::istringstream str(line);
      int mark;
      if ( str >> mark )
      {
         if (  mark >= 0 && mark <= 100)
         {
            return mark;
         }
      }
      std::cout << "Invalid input: " << line << std::endl;
      std::cout << "enter mark (0 - 100): " << std::endl;
   }

   // Unable to read.
   // Throw exception, or exit with an error message.
   return 0;
}
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/99Kdld).

Comment: Thanks, but how should i make the function to not take strings at this point?

Comment: @Sami, you'll have to use your strategy of `cin.clear()` and `cin.ignore()` but then you'll have to update the `while` loop a bit.

Comment: it does not work... when i implement cin.clear() and cin.ignore() strings still pass through and so do negative integers for 1 loop, only after that does the function prompt for different input, and records the nearest correct input but into the next loop

Comment: yeah well, the problem i have is that the code takes bad input as answer, so for me, it is placed into the array instead of being deleted and replaced by a valid value, and that makes the point of my array, which is calculating a average and so on, pointless since the invalid input messes up all the calculations

Comment: @Sami, with the updated `GetMark` function, you should never get an invalid value in `marks`.